# Manual installation of Python package

Tags: python, linux

I wrote a small python program and now I want to install and use it on my system.

Program structure:

```
projectname
|--src
|  |--main.py #import file1
|  |--file1.py #import file2
|  |--file2.py
|--LICENSE
|--README.md
|--setup.py
```

I did `sudo python setup.py install`, but now I only able to run it with `/usr/bin/main.py`. What should I do, to be able to run it by only typing a `projectname`?

EDIT: Setup.py content:

```
setuptools.setup(
    name="projectname",
    version="0.0.1",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "projectname = projectname.src/main:main"
        ]
    },
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

Comment: Make a script...

Comment: Make an alias on your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setuptools' [entry points](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) in your setup.py.

Example from the documentation:

```py
setup(
    # other arguments here...
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "foo = my_package.some_module:main_func",
            "bar = other_module:some_func",
        ],
        "gui_scripts": [
            "baz = my_package_gui:start_func",
        ]
    }
)
```

With your structure, create file `src/__init__.py`:

```py
from . import main
```

and lets say that this is `src/main.py`:

```py
def main():
    print("Hello world")
```

Finally, `setup.py` can be:

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="projectname",
    version="0.0.1",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "projectname = src:main.main"
        ]
    },
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

Comment: So how should it be in my case? `projectname = projectname.src/main:main` gives me an error. I am a little unfamiliar with the syntax.

Comment: @Arden  Can you please add the contents of `setup.py` to your original question?

Comment: I have a `main` function in the `main` file and also `if __name__ == '__main__': curses.wrapper(main)`, if that is important.

Comment: @Arden First, you need to create file `src/__init__.py` with contents `from . import main`. Then, the setup line becomes `"projectname = src:main.main"`.

Also see https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.py for an extensive example of a project.
I would also advise you to rename the `src` folder because this is the module name.